# using @postconstruct and @Scheduled annotation together

Tags: java, spring

I am new learner and using spring annotation for configuration Can i use both @PostConstruct and  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L)
on same method as given below ? if yes what should be the annotation to class ?

```
@Component
public class Cache {

     @PostConstruct
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L)
     public void refreshCache() {
     ...
     }

}
```

Comment: If you are using spring boot, then `@EnableScheduling` annotation should be specified together with `@SpringBootApplication` and make sure your task can be scanned by your spring boot application, which is actually a common bean that can be annotated by `@Component` as you've done.

Comment: I am not using Spring boot

Comment: If not, you can see the javadoc about class `EnableScheduling`.

    <beans>
        <task:annotation-driven scheduler="taskScheduler"/>
        <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="42"/>
        <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
            <task:scheduled ref="myTask" method="work" fixed-rate="1000"/>
        </task:scheduled-tasks>
        <bean id="myTask" class="com.foo.MyTask"/>
    </beans>

Comment: Actually, if you have normal `applicationContext.xml`, you can enable the annotation detection by `<context:annotation-config .../>` and together with annotation `<context:component-scan .../>`. It should be simple to use. The full namespace is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd`

Comment: I am not using any xml file, everything is on annotation...!

Comment: [https://github.com/soiff-spring/spring-boot-example](https://github.com/soiff-spring/spring-boot-example) this example is spring boot based application, which contains only annotations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your annotations in the class are correct. But you better use:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L, initialDelay=0)
public void refreshCache() {
```

without the `@PostConstruct` because:

1. Only one method in the class can be annotated with `@PostConstruct`.
2. You can not throw checked exceptions from the method using `@PostConstruct`.
3. Others will not have autowired this component.

There are more causes but I stop here.

Comment: I Have tried @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60L * 1000L, initialDelay=0) but it's not invoking method..!

Comment: @Shailesh Then, something is wrong outside of the class. Please post your `web.xml`.

Comment: Actually I am not using any XML for Configuration, it's purely annotation based configuration

Comment: @Shailesh You have no `web.xml`?

Comment: I do not have web.xml I am having POM.xml, ehcache.xml and log4j.xml files..! I am configuring it through by coding..!

Comment: @Shailesh So you have any class having the `WebServletContextListener` annotation?

Comment: I had a similar situation. But note that `initialDelay` is not compatible with `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use any xml, this example should be what you want, which actually is a spring boot application. https://github.com/soiff-spring/spring-boot-example

---

My full example is here: https://github.com/soiff-spring/spring-mvc-example

Please pay attention to following file and class:

1. `hello-servlet.xml`
2. `HelloScheduler`

Packaing this project and put it in your tomcat container and start your tomcat, you'll see the log as following:

```
20:06:53.003 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO xyz.cloorc.example.springmvc.HelloScheduler - 1480594013001 : hello world ...
20:06:54.001 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO xyz.cloorc.example.springmvc.HelloScheduler - 1480594014001 : hello world ...
20:06:55.001 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO xyz.cloorc.example.springmvc.HelloScheduler - 1480594015001 : hello world ...
20:06:56.002 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO xyz.cloorc.example.springmvc.HelloScheduler - 1480594016002 : hello world ...
20:06:57.000 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO xyz.cloorc.example.springmvc.HelloScheduler - 1480594017000 : hello world ...
20:06:58.002 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO xyz.cloorc.example.springmvc.HelloScheduler - 1480594018002 : hello world ...
```

Enjoy yourself.

Comment: As my research, only `@Scheduled` will take effect if annotation `@PostConstruct` is specified together.